Is TeX still the base of it all?
In many discussions I have learned, that there were many improvements over the years, making TeX more convinient. But, my question is: Is the original program still present and of use?
Down to the basics: Would it be possible, to present a really complicated document, from Latex or whatever highly stages are reached, and recode it, just using the original TeX, getting the same result?
Maybe, someone takes the challenge.

You asked two main questions: "Is the original program still present and of use?" Are you referring to "Knuth TeX"? If so, the answer to the first question is an unequivocal "yes". Please define "of use" in more detail. E.g., are you asking how many persons use Knuth TeX to create actual documents?

@Mico  I would Iike to see (really see) , how a highly developed (macroed) code would look, if it is coded in the most basic way. That would be Knuth's. In other discussions, I frequently run into the argument: "One would not do this nowadays".  Now, I just like to have the chance to compare the oldest codes with the newest.  It is about learning TeX.

@Mico Often, I am confronted with the argument: One has not to reinvent the wheel. Reinventing the wheel is not the same as the abiltiy to make one.

PlainTeX, LaTeX, and ConTeXt are macro libraries, or "formats", that are built on top of various TeX engines. Engines consist of executable code and a set of "primitive" commands. The main engines in use at present are KnuthTeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX. If I understand your objective correctly, you're looking for an example of code that uses KnuthTeX and only its built-in primitives to create a (presumably nontrivial) document. I've never actually heard of anyone who uses only the primitive commands to create a document. Knuth himself created the PlainTeX format to typeset "The TeXbook".

If you want to "learn TeX" using only KnuthTeX and the PlainTeX macro library, an excellent place to start would be The TeXbook by Don Knuth.

doesn;t the TeX Book source satisfy your criteria? it's a complex document and certainly coded in nothing beyond core + plain.

I added my opinion to this issue to the comment here before I have found this thread.

There are 1000s of documents out there that use either plain TeX or work with LaTeX before e-TeX was required - so yes, there are many docs that don't require engine extensions. However, as others have said, even if you look at DEK's use of TeX, macros are used to provide functionality on top of primitives. It's really not clear what you are after.

LaTeX requires e-TeX extensions so it won't run with the original TeX.

the answer is clearly true you could go even lower and cut out tex altogether and just hand write the PDF, all that is required is the ability to chose a characfer from a font and position it at some point in the page.  what is your actual question?

I added  [tag:tex-core]` you had tagged it as plain-tex but if you really mean is everything based on plain then that is a different answer "no" latex does not imput plain tex at all,

Thanks for all the comments.

@cfr You misunderstood the question. I do not want to have an original TeX - document, I want to see, if  modern and highly developed documents can be (re)coded with tex-core.  I really ask you to read more carefully.

@cfr Sorry about the last sentence, it was unpolite.

frankly, I didn't understand your question well enough to misunderstand it. for the record, I did read it carefully. I read it at least thrice. but I could not figure out what you were asking. note that I'm not the only one who read it that way as others suggested looking at existing plain documents, too.

@cfr
Ok, my question has lead to discussion, which was not intended.

@cfr I do not know, why my questions appear as complicated. I just want to know, how someone defines the command \section (or others)  in TeX-core. It is not about reading the TeXBook. I am asking the community, Asking is not to be discussed.

All current formats apart from the (dvi) plain tex use at least the etex extensions (either by using the etex.ch change file or using equivalent code as in luatex)
Some etex extensions are easy to emulate using classic TeX some less so,
For example the number of count registers is increased from 256 to 32,768
so if you have codes using 300 registers it is in principle possible to make some complicated scheme localy saving values in macros and restoring to registers when doing arithmetic, but it is tricky to do in general in a way that will work with the existing codes. Note the pain originally making pictex work with latex, where in order to avoid running out of registers a fragile scheme of re-using latex registers that were "unlikely" to be used in the same scope as pictex had do be devised as you could not simply load pictex and standard latex packages without running out of registers,
If "all" in your title includes luatex then of course that allows you to call Lua functions which are certainly not based on TeX.
You originally tagged this as plain-tex but I interpreted your question as meaning tex-core as most used formats such as LaTeX do not input the plain.tex macros at all.

That said, any (print) document that you can produce in any tex-related format you could produce just using plain TeX or not using TeX at all. All you need is the ability to extract a character from a font and position it on the page so you could do this just with TeX primitives (if the fonts are converted to tfm) or just hand written PDF. You may not want to do that for a complicated document, but it is certainly possible in theory.

Thank you for sharing your insight and experience.

tex still gets you Knuth's unmodified TeX82 in TeX Live, but etex links to pdfTeX with all the PDF stuff disabled.

@MaxChernoff TeX90, surely?

@MaxChernoff sorry I had mis-remembered I'll fix, thanks

@JosephWright We've had this discussion before, but there is no such thing as "TeX90" IMO: when Knuth rewrote TeX in WEB (during 1980–1982) he called the program "TeX82" to distinguish it from "TeX78" the earlier version he had written in SAIL (and which others had ported/rewritten into their respective computer systems; in contrast the choice of Pascal/WEB was so that it would be "portable"—Pascal was widely in use for teaching—so that everyone would get the same results from the program called "tex"/"TEX"/… on their system, and this is also the reason for the unusual TeX license). (contd…)

@JosephWright (…contd) This TeX has gone through changes, including "Version 2.992 introduced major changes for 8-bit extensions (September 1989)", but it is still called TeX82 per tex.web (see §1 and §2 on page 3 or the title line at top of every page). "TeX90" is a name that mainly Joseph Wright uses, apparently as a synonym for TeX version-3-or-later (i.e. the version after the most major changes), but it is not a usage that accords with any official sources IMO. :)

@ShreevatsaR Sure, but v3 was released in 1990, which is what i tend to go with - my wider point was that 'TeX82' implies 7-bit, whereas a current TeX system has an 8-bit Knuth TeX

@JosephWright but the program is called tex82 even so:-) tex.web still have \def\title{\TeX82} even in version 3.x

Though David's answer is perfect, just adding some more basic background/context. (Though it may be simply repeating it…)
You can ask your question “Is TeX still the base of it all?” at the level of programs (sometimes called "engines" in the TeX world) or (input) formats.
As programs go, the original TeX is still available in modern TeX distributions (it is what you will get if you invoke the program as tex, per the Knuth license/request), but almost all users today invoke one of the other programs like pdfTeX or XeTeX or LuaTeX, rather than the original TeX. These programs are still based on the original TeX program in some way or the other, especially for the “core” functions of choosing where the line breaks go, etc, but but (as explained in the previous link) they provide features like loading fonts in modern formats, or “primitives” that many macros (such as in “packages” that you may be using) have come to depend on. For a rough idea, as I mentioned elsewhere, in terms of lines of code, eTeX, pdfTeX, and XeTeX are roughly 15%, 50–60%, and (relying heavily on system libraries) 35% bigger than Knuth TeX, respectively.
At the level of “formats” (like LaTeX, ConTeXt, opTeX, Knuth's original “plain TeX”, eplain, etc), these, though usually implemented as macros on top of the TeX “engine”, are substantial pieces of software in themselves (if you include all the packages you use, possibly more lines of code than the TeX program itself!). [Surprisingly I cannot find a canonical answer on this site about the difference between formats (unlike the previous link for the programs), but this answer shows a “Hello World“ in plain TeX, LaTeX, and ConTeXt.] These macros, for most part, use features available in the original TeX program, but many of these formats (like LaTeX) use here-and-there some of the extensions in the later programs, so as a result will not work with the original TeX program.
But you also ask in the question whether it's possible to “recode”, and of course (as David mentioned) it is possible in theory to “recode” anything by writing all the code yourself, e.g. do all the “document” stuff (numbering of sections and cross-references, etc) externally and use TeX just for the line breaks, or even not use TeX at all and manually lay out glyphs on the page.

obviously a +1 even though I stopped reading after the first sentence:-)

@DavidCarlisle perfect :D

OK, we can go to a  historical research. See also this page.
Knuth froze TeX, Metafont and Computer Modern fonts development in 1990, see TeXtament. He applies only bugs fixing in an ever-increasing period of time: 1992, 1993, 1995, 1998, 2002, 2007, 2013, and 2020. Each bug fixing increases the number of digits in TeX and Metafont versions. Now, we have TeX version 3.141592653.
The TeX82 is written in web programming language (literate programming) and it enables an existence of special patches. Two today used TeX engines based on these patches are pdfTeX and XeTeX. If Knuth does a change in TeX, then the patches can be applied and the Knuth's changes are automatically overwritten in new versions of pdfTeX and XeTeX. The LuaTeX engine has its own sources, primarily transformed from ancient web system, but manually corrected and now managed separately.
Today, we are using LuaTeX engine (it is preferred for new users) or XeTeX engine (it is not developed today unfortunatelly) or pdfTeX engine (it doesn't support Unicode fonts unfortunately). The LuaTeX engine has its fork LuaMetaTeX. The classical TeX is present in TeX distributions too, IMHO only as a historical reminder of what was in the beginning.
Plain TeX is a basic set of macros distributed together with TeX and documented in Knuth's the TeXbook. All other macro sets/formats (LaTeX, ConTeXt, OpTeX) were initially based on the plain TeX but they add a lot of additional features and now, they sometimes abandon the original plain TeX concept (LaTeX re-defines \line or \bigskip macros or \end TeX primitive, for example). The closest to plain TeX is OpTeX, although it implements a huge number of other features.
The Knuth's idea that "TeX will give the same results 100 years from now" (see TeXtament) is probably true (we can test it now, more than 40 years from TeX born) but it has very limited usability. It can be applied only to documents with pure text written in ancient Computer modern fonts. Whenever other font was used or a graphic were included (which is common case in documents), then problems occur. Graphics, colors etc. were solved by \specials 40 years ago and these specials did the DVI (device independent) TeX output to be totally device dependent. So, if you have such an old document, you have to reinterpret the colors instructins, graphic insertions etc. from the languages of devices used at that time to technology used today. So, typical old documents are not simply processable today.
For example, I recently needed to re-compile my TeXbook naruby because somebody needed to try to apply machine translation of this book to English.
The book was written in 1999 and it uses only an 8bit fork of Computer Modern fonts "CSfonts" (still present in TeX distributions) and it was processed by pdftex. I was unable to re-create the book from sources due to two specific characters from a Metofnot font cmpex10 which is not present today. I had to use a special replacement solution for these two characters.
To your second question: If you stick to Knuth's TeX then you have to decide a set of specials used for colors, graphic insertions, hyperlinks etc. These are features typically present in today's documents but they were unsolved by classical TeX. Then you can produce DVI and then apply a conversion software from this DVI to today used document format (PDF). You can see that this is not time-stable solution, because we don't know what document format will be used in 50 years and what \specials and conversion software will be applicable in this future.
OK, maybe, your question was not about graphic, colors, hyperlinks etc, but only about macros. I.e. if today used macros can be re-writable using only TeX primitives from classical Knuth's TeX. The answer is: it is very very difficult. You will run into some obstacles very often. I give simple example (inspired from your previous question about \ifx...\undefined). You can replace \ifcsname#1\endcsname by {\expandafter}\expandafter\ifx \csname#1\endcsname\undefined but this solution cannot be expandable. On the other hand \ifcsname#1\endcsname is expandable but it isn't present in classical TeX. And one day there may be a situation where you will need to have your macro expandable...
